# Looking for a way to make solar eclipse maps in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Leaflet novice here. I'm looking for a way to make a map of coming eclipses in Leaflet (e.g., https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/map/2020-june-21) for a research project. Any advice on how to get started?

Comment: I would start by either a) creating geometries (lines, polygons) of the areas where the eclipse is visible, or b) reading the source code of https://github.com/joergdietrich/Leaflet.Terminator to see how building the data on-the-fly looks like.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, turns out that datavizforall.org has some excellent leaflet templates for inputting geojson data, and that Mathematica can output eclipse paths as geojson files. Still working on this project but we're making good progress.